# Having problems with slash direction in Roxygen2 package

Tags: r, backslash, roxygen2

I get the following error when I try to run roxygen2 using

```
roxygen2::roxygenize() or devtools::document() or devtools::load_all()
```

Error:

```
Error in read.dcf(file, keep.white = "Authors@R") : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file, keep.white = "Authors@R") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\peterfantastic\Documents\Folder1\Folder2/DESCRIPTION', 
  probable reason 'Permission denied'
```

I'm assuming it's because the slashes need to all be forward slashes, but I don't know how to change this in a package.

Windows 7

version.string R version: 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

nickname: Wooden Christmas-Tree